# Procmail: Denying special privileges for "/etc/procmailrcs/default.rc"

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, email, postfix, procmail

I'm trying to setup postfix, dovecot and procmail to work together with virtual users. In the end I want to have virtual users and the possibility to add rules to sort incoming rules. For the last thing, I need procmail (right?).

When I send an email to my server, I don't get it in my Maildir, and see this in mail.log:

```
Jun 17 21:01:03 cs postfix/smtpd[24811]: connect from dub0-omc2-s13.dub0.hotmail.com[157.55.1.152]
Jun 17 21:01:03 cs postfix/smtpd[24811]: D8C9F44D88: client=dub0-omc2-s13.dub0.hotmail.com[157.55.1.152]
Jun 17 21:01:03 cs postfix/cleanup[24816]: D8C9F44D88: message-id=<DUB115-W85D8D79486AEC1D4346693C0830@phx.gbl>
Jun 17 21:01:04 cs postfix/qmgr[24806]: D8C9F44D88: from=<my-test-email>, size=1617, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 17 21:01:04 cs procmail[24818]: Denying special privileges for "/etc/procmailrcs/default.rc"
Jun 17 21:01:04 cs postfix/smtpd[24811]: disconnect from dub0-omc2-s13.dub0.hotmail.com[157.55.1.152]
Jun 17 21:01:04 cs postfix/pipe[24817]: D8C9F44D88: to=<my-virtual-email>, relay=virtualprocmail, delay=0.18, delays=0.15/0/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via virtualprocmail service)
Jun 17 21:01:04 cs postfix/qmgr[24806]: D8C9F44D88: removed
```

How can I fix the line "Denying special privileges" procmail spits out?

```
camilstaps@cs:/# ls -al /etc/procmailrcs
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  vmail   4096 Jun 17 19:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 97 root  root    4096 Jun 17 19:47 ..
-rw-------  1 vmail postfix   44 Jun 17 19:48 default.rc
```

Here's my `/etc/postfix/master.cf`:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
submission inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
virtualprocmail unix - n n - - pipe flags=DRXhuq user=vmail
  argv=/usr/bin/procmail -m E_SENDER=$sender E_RECIPIENT=$recipient ER_USER=$user ER_DOMAIN=$domain ER_DETAIL=$extension NEXTHOP=$nexthop /etc/procmailrcs/default.rc
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

I'm on Ubuntu Server 13.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man procmail` states:

```
Denying special privileges for "x"
  Procmail will not take on the identity that comes with the rcfile because 
  a security violation was found (e.g.  -p or variable assignments on the
  command line) or procmail had insufficient privileges to do so.
```

I the presented case the error message is caused by `variable assignments on the command line` e.g. `E_SENDER=$sender`.

**Possible Fixes:**

Use another "non special to procmail" directory to store the script instead of /etc/procmailrcs
(As I understand /etc/procmailrcs magic is not required in the case)
**OR**
Pass use positional parameters on the command line and assigment in *.rc file

procmail script invocation:

```
/usr/bin/procmail -m /etc/procmailrcs/default.rc $sender $recipient $user $domain $extension $nexthop
```

procmail script (initial part):

```
# DROPRIVS - procmail magical variable, assigment causes side effects
DROPPRIVS=yes

E_SENDER=$1 
E_RECIPIENT=$2 
ER_USER=$3 
ER_DOMAIN=$4 
ER_DETAIL=$5 
NEXTHOP=$6
```

Comment: Thanks! The error is gone since I moved the file. However, the mail isn't delivered in my Maildir - do you also know why that is?

Comment: Use `LOGFILE`, `VERBOSE` and (optionally) `LOGABSTRACT` in your procmail script to locate the problems (see `man procmailrc`)

Comment: Thanks! That really helped. The problem was procmail used the mbox format, not the Maildir format. I solved it by adding a slash (`/`) to the end of `DEFAULT` in the procmail script. (You might want to edit that in somehow, perhaps on askubuntu as well). Everything's working now, thanks a lot!

Comment: @200_success Fixed. Thanks for the hint.